# React native, cannot convert function result to number

Tags: javascript, react-native

I need to convert result of this function to number:

```js
const [nbChambres, setNbChambres] = useState(1);
const [nbNuits, setNbNuits] = useState(1); 

function calculatePrixTotal(){
    const nbChambresInt = parseInt(nbChambres) || 1;
    const nbNuitsInt = parseInt(nbNuits) || 1;
    let priceNumber = price.substring(1);

    if(priceNumber.includes(',')) {
        priceNumber = parseInt(priceNumber.replace(',', ''));
        const prixTotal = String(priceNumber * nbNuitsInt * nbChambresInt);
            return prixTotal.slice(0, prixTotal.length - 3) + "," + prixTotal.slice(prixTotal.length - 3);
    } else {
        return String(parseInt(priceNumber) * nbNuitsInt * nbChambresInt);
    }
}
```

Here is the function I made to make the subtraction, I got `NaN` as the result:

```js
function calculateNewMoneyBalance(){
    const calcInt = parseFloat(calculatePrixTotal);
    const moneyInt = parseInt(MoneyBalance);
    console.log(typeof moneyInt);
    return parseInt(moneyInt - calcInt);
}
```

Comment: You're passing `calculatePrixTotal` into `parseFloat()` without actually calling it. Since a function is not a number, that will result in `NaN`.

Answer (score -2):

Hi add method to function call

`let calcInt= parseFloat(calculatePrixTotal())`

Comment: Doesn't work: consol.log(typeof calculatePrixTotal) is function, consol.log( typeof calcInt) is undefined

Comment: you need to call function like`calculatePrixTotal()` it will return some number as you mentioned then you can convert that number to float. so you can call like `parseFloat(calculatePrixTotal())` instead of `parseFloat(calculatePrixTotal)`